# Can I remove font-size declarations from document with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, stylesheet, font-size

I want to make a Chrome extension (so decent & documented Javascript) that removes ALL `font-size` declarations from a document.

Document stylesheets:

```
document.styleSheets
```

Stylesheet rules:

```
document.styleSheets[0].rules
```

Rule declaration (or whatcha call em?):

```
document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.fontSize
```

How do I remove that last one? I want to use the browser's standards, **so not set everything to 100%**. Is there a way to remove all `font-size` styles?

(I don't care about inline styles or javascript added styles.)

**BTW**
Anybody know why `.rules` is empty (`null`) for the `all.css` stylesheet of Stack Overflow? There are a LOT of styles in there and Chrome uses them. Why can't I access them in document.styleSheets?

Comment: Can you find the browser's default CSS template, and then extract the values from there?

Comment: That would be A LOT of work. I would think resetting the user/page css is easier, but I might be wrong. `style.removeProperty('font-size')` does something, but I'm not exactly sure what. Maybe I'm approaching the problem/solution solution wrong (with document.styleSheets)..?

Comment: can you set all font-size to 'inherit' ?

Comment: It isn't null for `all.css`, just type `document.styleSheets` in the Chrome console and look at #0.

Comment: If I do that in Chrome and drill down I see `cssRules: null` and `rules: null`. The resource is being served from a separate domain, so I don't know whether JavaScript can access it.

Comment: The domain thing might be it, but that would still be odd: the parent document should be able to access its css rules, right? It's loading them, so it should be able to disable them, I'd think.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, because you can't access stylesheet rules loaded from another domain. This is a security restriction similar to AJAX *same origin policy*.

Answer (score 2):

What about injecting [custom css](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html) through manifest and overriding font sizes to default values:

```
* {font-size:1em !important;}
h1 {font-size:2em !important;}
h2 {font-size:1.5em !important;}
h3 {font-size:1.17em !important;}
h5 {font-size:.83em !important;}
h6 {font-size:.67em !important;}
```

User agent stylesheet doesn't declare sizes for many elements, mostly only for headers. I couldn't find exact default stylesheet for Chrome, but [here](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/) is a few from other browsers, should be something very similar.

Comment: +1 for probably the easiest solution. FWIW, [HTML4's recommended default stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) confirms these values. These are also true for Chrome.

Comment: That's not the easiest solution... All `!important` won't be overwritten and I'd just be adding more CSS. **edit** Yeah so maybe it is the easiest solution =( but I want to reset `outline` and `line-height` as well...

Comment: (Btw adding it in the manifest won't work because I want it behind a browser action button but that's details.)

Answer (score -3):

1. Try setting it to nothing `= ''`
2. Try setting it to `null`
3. You can try the javascript `delete` function:
   http://www.openjs.com/articles/delete.php

Comment: Don't work. `...style.removeProperty('font-size')` works but somehow doesn't get all font styles...

Comment: As far as I can tell: You can't access stylesheets from another domain. The first two is the same. You also don't take into account that it can be inside a combined `font: ...` declaration. The last one is totally incorrect because a.) `delete` with host objects can be rather unpredictable b.) `delete` is an *operator* not a function - http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/